# Correctly sending POST data to php with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been having an issue for the past few hours with correctly sending any GET or POST values to my php script. When I remove my if statement checking for the POST var, the data is returned fine. Not getting any errors in the browser console. Anyone know what might be going on? Thanks in advance!

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newhtml = '';
    var seller = $("#seller").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {seller: seller},
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
          if(typeof item == 'object') {
          newhtml += '<div>Removed to save space</div>';
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
    })


    $('#results').append(newhtml);
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr + "\n" + err);
    }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
//Return the data
if($_POST['seller']){
    echo json_encode($products);
}
```

Comment: If you check the network panel in your browser, please look what is actually transfered here to and from the server (in case of the error)

Comment: Use double quote `" "` for string checking. `if(typeof item == "object") {`

Comment: Use if($_POST['seller'] != ''){ //Code }

Answer (score 0):

you have to format your if condition correct way

```
if(isset($_POST['seller']) && trim($_POST['seller'])!=''){
    echo json_encode($products);
}
```

your condition checks for whether it is true or false.(i.e boolean)

Comment: That was a good catch, but ended up not being my issue, it looks like the documents were being cached by the server and not updating, I moved all the jquery from the external script to an inline script and it all works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use === in place of ==

Hope this will help.